# How to configure munin to run on nginx instead of apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, nginx, monitoring, munin

I have couple of production ubuntu 10.04 ec2 instances which are running ruby on rails web app using NGINX. I need to deploy munin for the production servers to monitor it. But the thing is I tried couple of examples suggested by google. I have DNS parked in Route 53. SO how do I enable munin to monitor and how do I get the graph via HTTP.

And also my another question is there any way to monitor my AWS MYSQL RDS using munin. If yes give me heads up.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Munin generates a set of static HTML files, normally to `/var/cache/www/munin`. You can set up nginx to point to this directory or set up a static subdomain with its root set to this domain:

```
server {
    listen       *:80;
    server_name  munin.yourdomain.com;

    root   /var/cache/munin/www;

    [...other options go here...]

}
```

For your second question, you can of course monitor RDS instances like any other mysql instances. Just use a mysql plugin of your choice (for example the [munin-mysql](https://github.com/kjellm/munin-mysql/) set of plugins) and point the connection string of the plugin to your RDS instance (in case of munin-mysql this should go in mysql.conf). Often these plugins are already available as a package for your distribution, too. Also make sure that the server you are running the plugin on is allowed to connect to RDS and has the necessary database privileges available.